# If $S$, $S'$, $V$ and $V'$ vector spaces with $S\cong S'$ and $V\cong V'$ then, $L(S,V)\cong L(S',V')$.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S$, $S'$, $V$ and $V'$ vector spaces with $S\cong S'$ and $V\cong V'$ then, $L(S,V)\cong L(S',V')$.

I know that if S and V has finite dimensional then this problem is easy, but how to prove it is S or V has infinite dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi : S\to S'$ and $\psi V\to V'$ isomorphisms, then
$$\varPhi(f)=\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}$$
is an isomorphism between $L(S,V)$ and $L(S',V')$.

Comment: Thanks, did the math and it all worked.